# Chart display for two R Versions

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

I am trying to run the code below on two R versions, and do not have the same display. I want to display one value ('10') with one category only ('Feb') and this is not working for one of the versions, here you can see the output comparison:

[image]

And here is the code :

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")

data(citytemp)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Highcharter EXAMPLE"),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 8,
           highchartOutput("hcontainer",height = "500px")
    ),
    selectInput("option", label = "",  width = "100%",
                choices = c("Tokyo", "NY"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- citytemp[,c("month","tokyo","new_york")]
  data = data[data$month%in%c("Dec","Jan","Feb","Mar"),]
  choose_Option <- reactive({
    sort_option <- input$option
    if(sort_option=="Tokyo"){
      data = data[order(data$tokyo),]
    }
    else{
      data = data[order(data$new_york),]
    }
    return(data)
  })
  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({
    data = choose_Option()      
    data = data[data$month=="Feb",]
    chart <-  highchart() %>% 
      hc_chart(type = "bar") %>% 
      hc_title(text = "Monthly Average Temperature for main cities") %>% 
      hc_subtitle(text = "Source: WorldClimate.com") %>% 
      hc_xAxis(categories = data$month) %>% 
      hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Temperature (C)"),stackLabels=list(enabled=FALSE))%>% 
      hc_plotOptions(
        series=list(stacking="normal"))

    hc <- chart %>% hc_add_series(yAxis=0,name="Tokyo",data = 10,colorByPoint=TRUE,dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE) )

    return(hc)
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Do you have any suggestions about how I could correct my display in the version 3.2.0 ? Thank you, best regards, Madzia

Comment: Have you installed the packages in the R 3.2.0 version? you should reinstall  when you use new versions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! but can I use 3.2.2 highchart version on 3.2.0 version ? I have investigated further and R returns the following error: http://www.highcharts.com/errors/18

Comment: Hi @Madzia, when you data is a atomic element (length 1) you have to send it as a list: `hc_add_series(data = list(10))` (and remove that `hc_add_series(yAxis=0)` (more information in https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/155)

Comment: Thank you ! that works perfectly ! Best, Madzia